# Dynamic Drag Preview for Custom Tree View Component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I am working on creating a custom tree view component in my Angular application using Angular CDK Drag and Drop. I have implemented the drag and drop functionality to change the order of the nodes successfully. However, I am facing an issue with the drag preview.

Currently, when dragging a node, the entire hierarchy of nodes from top to bottom is shown in the drag preview. However, I want to show only the specific node being dragged in the preview, while keeping the other nodes visible in the list, and a can be dragged and dropped only that specific label.

I am trying to achieve something like this -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tree-with-drag-and-drop?file=main.ts

To achieve this, I have tried using an ng-template with the cdkDragPreview directive. Here is the relevant code snippet:

**Tree View Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tree-view',
  template: `
    <div class="tree-view">
      <div class="tree-view-wrapper">
        <ul class="tree-view-container">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let node of nodes">
            <tree-view-node [node]="node"></tree-view-node>
          </ng-container>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TreeViewComponent {
  @Input() nodes!: IHierarchyNode[];
}
```

**Tree View Node Component HTML**

```
<li cdkDrag class="tree-view-node" [cdkDragDisabled]="!isDraggable">
    <ng-container *cdkDragPreview>
        <div class="tree-view-node-drag-preview">
            <h6>{{ node.label }}</h6>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container
        *ngTemplateOutlet="treeNodeTemplate; context: { $implicit: node }"
    ></ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="node.expanded">
        <ul
            cdkDropList
            [@toggleHeight]
            class="tree-view-node-children"
            [cdkDropListData]="node.children"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
            [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="canEnterPredicate"
        >
            <ng-container *ngFor="let child of node.children">
                <tree-view-node
                    [node]="child"
                    [isDraggable]="node.children.length > 1"
                ></tree-view-node>
            </ng-container>
        </ul>
    </ng-container>
</li>
<ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node>
    <div
        class="tree-view-node-content"
        [class.tree-view-node-expanded]="node.expanded"
    >
        <div class="tree-view-node-content-left">
            <div class="tree-view-node-content-left-actions">
                <ng-container *ngIf="node.children && node.children.length > 0">
                    <a
                        class="tree-view-toggler"
                        (click)="onToggleTreeNode($event)"
                    >
                        <span class="material-symbols-rounded">
                            chevron_right
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </ng-container>
            </div>
            <div class="tree-view-node-content-left-label">
                <h6>{{ node.label }}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tree-view-node-content-right">
            <a
                tooltipPosition="top"
                [tooltipStyleClass]="'custom-tooltip'"
                [pTooltip]="'Edit ' + (node.key | titlecase)"
            >
                <span class="icon-edit"></span>
            </a>
            <a
                tooltipPosition="top"
                [tooltipStyleClass]="'custom-tooltip'"
                [pTooltip]="'Delete ' + (node.key | titlecase)"
            >
                <span class="icon-delete"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

**Tree View Node Component TS**

```
@Input('node') node!: IHierarchyNode;
@Input('isDraggable') isDraggable!: boolean;

public onToggleTreeNode(event: Event): void {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.node.expanded = !this.node.expanded;
    }

    public canEnterPredicate = (drag: CdkDrag, drop: CdkDropList): boolean => {
        const draggedNode: IHierarchyNode = drag.data;
        const targetNode: IHierarchyNode = drop.data[0];

        // Allow drop only if the labels match and the nodes are not the same
        return (
            draggedNode.label === targetNode.label && draggedNode !== targetNode
        );
    };

    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<IHierarchyNode[]>): void {
        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
            moveItemInArray(
                event.container.data,
                event.previousIndex,
                event.currentIndex
            );
        } else {
            transferArrayItem(
                event.previousContainer.data,
                event.container.data,
                event.previousIndex,
                event.currentIndex
            );
        }
    }
```

**Parent Component TS**

```
const data = [{"_id":"647fab1afda17a6fbe7d5d93","name":"R/F","type":"modality","children":[{"_id":"647fab46fda17a6fbe7d5dbc","name":"Flexavision","type":"family","children":[{"_id":"647fab5ffda17a6fbe7d5df3","name":"Remote","type":"application","children":[{"_id":"647fab7cfda17a6fbe7d5e37","name":"Flexavision","type":"product","children":[{"_id":"647fabb7fda17a6fbe7d5e97","name":"F4","type":"configuration","children":[]},{"_id":"648763319c946dbccad156fc","name":"F45","type":"configuration","children":[]},{"_id":"648763d49c946dbccad158ad","name":"F4","type":"configuration","children":[]}]}]}]},{"_id":"6487cb1e9c946dbccad1770a","name":"SonialVision","type":"family","children":[{"_id":"6487cb319c946dbccad17745","name":"Remote","children":[{"_id":"6487cb3f9c946dbccad1778e","name":"SonialVision","type":"product","children":[{"_id":"6487cb749c946dbccad177f5","name":"G4LX","type":"configuration","children":[]}]}],"type":"application"}]}]}] as IProductHierarchy[];

this.products = this.generateProductTreeView(data);

private generateProductTreeView(
        products: IProductHierarchy[]
    ): IHierarchyNode[] {
        return products.map((product) => {
            //On each iteration for first node storing the data
            //This data will passed to each tree node to create the route params
            //If we pass product directly than as the iteration moves to configuration
            //Upperlevels hierarchy will not be accessable
            //That why passed the top level hierarchy to each tree node
            if (product.type === 'modality') {
                this.productData = product;
            }

            const node: IHierarchyNode = {
                expanded: false,
                _id: product._id,
                key: product.type,
                label: product.name,
                data: this.productData,
                children: this.generateProductTreeView(product.children)
            };

            return node;
        });
    }
```

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<tree-view [nodes]="products"></tree-view>
```